# weird behaviour of setting new File Name in android

Tags: java, android, file

I need to create new file in andorid with Java. I do it like this :

```
 public static File getAbosoluteFile(String relativePath, Context context) {
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            return new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),  "AE "  +".jpg");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "internal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return new File(context.getFilesDir(), "AE"  +".jpg");
        }
    }
```

but when I put it like this - it works properly, but when I change the name , for example using string from the method :

```
 public static String getCurrentDate()
 {
     String returnDate = null;
     Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
     int minute = currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
     String editedMinute;
     if (minute<10)
         editedMinute = "0"  + Integer.toString(minute);
     else 
         editedMinute = Integer.toString(minute);
     returnDate= (Integer.toString((currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)) + "/" +Integer.toString(currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/" +Integer.toString(currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR))  + " " +
             Integer.toString(currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" + editedMinute);
     return returnDate;

 }
```

So , even when I use `return new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),  "12/12/12 "  +".jpg");`
the file is doesn't create too. I tried to use the screening in the name - thought reason is in this, but the same result. 
Is Java's `new File(File dir, String name)` is so depending to the name format? Or what the reason ?

Comment: You cannot have a ":" in a filepath. There are other characters that are forbidden also. The LogCat will have told you! You can use "/" but then you are introducing subdirs.

Comment: why minusing ? I added the description.

Comment: You will have been downvoted (not by me by the way) while you did not use `String relativePath` in your first method. Further you did not show how you used the return value of `getCurrentDate()`for a call to `getAbosoluteFile()`. Wich would not have worked while you do not use the parameter. And.. instead of showing the code for `getCurrentDate()` you could better have told that you tried to use "12/13:23344" in your pathname. And you should have posted the LogCat. In short: a very bad post...

Comment: greenapps, thank you for the explanation. Will  consider in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `/` in your file name. It is used as a file separator.

For eg.If you have a folder named `App` in your SD card and in it a sub folder called `Sub` the path is something like `mnt/sdcard/App/Sub`(`mnt/sdcard` is just for example it is not fixed)

So you can see why you can't use `/` in a file name.

Try using `_` in place of `/`.